# What is the best and fastest way to extract substring from string?

Tags: c++

What is the best and most effective way to extract a string from a string? I will need this operation to be preforms thousands of times.

I have this string and I'd like to extract the URL. The URL is always after the "url=" substring until the end of the string. For example:

```
http://foo.com/fooimage.php?d=AQA4GxxxpcDPnw&w=130&h=130&url=http00253A00252F00252Fi1.img.com00252Fvi00252FpV4Taseyww00252Fhslt.jpg
```

and I need to extract the

```
http00253A00252F00252Fi1.img.com00252Fvi00252FpV4Taseyww00252Fhslt.jpg
```

I want to avoid using split and such.

Comment: You want to avoid using `split`? Why? And what have you tried?

Comment: `std::string::find()` and `std::string::substr()` seems the simplest way to do this. I do not know if this the fastest way though. In order to determine that you would have to compare (profile) it to other methods of extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string inStr;

//this step is necessary
size_t pos = inStr.find("url=")；

if(pos !=  std::string::npos){
  char const * url = &inStr[pos + 4];
  // it is fine to  do any read only operations with url
  // if you would apply some modifications to url, please make a copy string
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you absolutely need the results as a string, you'll have to measure,
but I doubt that anything will be significantly faster than the most 
intuitive:

```
std::string
getTrailer( std::string const& original, std::string const& key )
{
    std::string::const_iterator pivot
        = std::search( original.begin(), original.end(), key.begin(), key.end() );
    return pivot == original.end()
        ? std::string()  // or some error condition...
        : std::string( pivot + key.size(), original.end() );
}
```

However, the fastest way is probably not to extract the string at all,
but to simply keep it as a pair of iterators.  If you need this a lot,
it might be worth defining a `Substring` class which encapsulates this.
(I've found a mutable variant of this to be very effective when
parsing.)  If you go this way, don't forget that the iterators will
become invalid if the original string disappears; be sure to convert
anything you want to keep into a string before this occurs.

Comment: +1 for pair of iterators, it's a perfectly respectable way of representing a sub-range of some other range. In this case the desired substring is a suffix, so we don't have to do any special work to ensure it's nul terminated beyond what we'd do to ensure the whole containing string is nul terminated. But in general using a pair of iterators means that it's the end iterator that tells where the end is, not a nul terminator, which means it can work for substrings that are not suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `std::string::find()` :

if its a char* than just move the pointer to the position right after "url="

```
yourstring = (yourstring + yourstring.find("url=")+4 );
```

I cant think of anything faster..

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into the boost libraries.
For example [boost::split()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id1113872.html)

I don't know how they actually perform in terms of speed, but it's definitely worth a try.

Comment: boost::split is a generic function. it is often slower.